# Use two WaitOne() and Continue if one of them is Set()

Tags: c#, multithreading, waitone

- I have a thread which is responsible for ***scheduled*** transferring of files.
- The files transferring ***schedule*** is mentioned in an XML file, which can be changed by the user at any time.
- I have created a `FileSystemWatcher`, which is responsible to keep watching the XML file and notify if there is any change in the XML file (so that we can get the new schedule value). This `FileSystemWatcher` notifies by setting a `AutoResetEvent` called `_waitTillXmlChanges`.

**Question:** Once a scheduled file transferring is done, I want to put that thread into Waiting state until one of the following two conditions is met:

(a). Either the next file transfer schedule date is reached

(b). OR the `FileSystemWatcher` has notified about a change in the .XML file

***How can I make my file transferring thread waiting for above two conditions (two `AutoResetEvent` waiting) and proceed if anyone of them is `Set()` ?***

Comment: Use [`WaitHandle.WaitAny()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: IMO you don't really need threads for that. Just use events from `FileSystemWatcher` and based on that call your routine with `Task<>`. File transfer you can schedule on every windows os using task scheduler.

Comment: @m.rogalski: I actually needs threads because this is only one part of my application. Actually different operations have to be performed by different threads if there is any change in the .XML file happens.

Comment: @skm Oh... Sorry, I've misunderstood that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles)`, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int eventNr = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[]{autoResetEvent1, autoResetEvent2});
```